# Не получается спарсить страницу в Simple Html Dom Parser

Tags: php, dom

С помощью цикла получается значение массива и при вставке его для парсинга с помощью библиотеки(*в массиве находятся урлы,которые нужно спарсить*) все ломается и получается такая ошибка -

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/часть пути/public_html/часть/parse.php on line 27

А при вставке обычной переменной в которой находится уже готовый адрес **все работает**

Код:

```
       $fileget = file('id.txt');
       $c = count($fileget);
       $i = 0;
      while ( $i < $c) {
       $html = file_get_html($fileget[$i]);
       // echo "$html";
      foreach($html->find('.pp_last_activity') as $element) 
        $go = $element->plaintext;
//       $r = rand(1,100);
     ...
```

**VarDump**:

> array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "http://vk.com/chalimov " [1]=> string(22) "http://vk.com/bezhan" }

Comment: Почему в echo вы выводите $i-ый элемент, а в функции берете нулевой элемент массива?

Comment: Ошибочка.Сейчас подправлю.Просто дебажил

Comment: var_dump($fileget) покажите.

Comment: Добавил в пост...

Comment: Вообще-то, не должно работать ни так, ни эдак. Если включите отображение всех ошибок, то увидите, что вконтакте возвращает 404 ошибку на любое обращение к его страницам:  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Странно,у меня работает....

Comment: В начало кода поставьте error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Так проблема в том что вроде пихаешь уже готовую переменную и все работает.А так с массивом почему-то возвращает ошибку.Что-то не так в коде скорее всего...Не может же такого быть

Comment: Что пишет в ошибка при error_reporting(E_ALL); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что функция file() возвращает элементы массива с переводом строк на конце элементов.
Вот как выглядит массив

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'http://vk.com/chalimov
' (length=24)
  1 => string 'http://vk.com/bezhan
' (length=22)
```

Обработайте каждый элемент массива функцией `trim` вот так

```
$fileget = array_map('trim', $fileget);
```

После этого массив примет правильный для дальнейшего использования вид

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'http://vk.com/chalimov' (length=22)
  1 => string 'http://vk.com/bezhan' (length=20)
```